# Incorporate body of message while redirecting url in fastCGI?

Tags: c++, nginx, fastcgi

I am implementing fastCGI in c++ along with nginx. Until now, I am able to develop basic http request method and some url redirection. But, I am not able to send the body of message while redirecting from post url to another post url. Below is my code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "string.h"
    #include "fcgio.h"
    #include <fcgi_stdio.h>
    #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace boost;

    // Maximum bytes
    const unsigned long STDIN_MAX = 1000000;

    /**
     * Note this is not thread safe due to the static allocation of the
     * content_buffer.
     */
    string get_request_content(const FCGX_Request & request) {
        char * content_length_str = FCGX_GetParam("CONTENT_LENGTH", request.envp);
        unsigned long content_length = STDIN_MAX;

        if (content_length_str) {
            content_length = strtol(content_length_str, &content_length_str, 10);
            if (*content_length_str) {
                cerr << "Can't Parse 'CONTENT_LENGTH='"
                     << FCGX_GetParam("CONTENT_LENGTH", request.envp)
                     << "'. Consuming stdin up to " << STDIN_MAX << endl;
            }

            if (content_length > STDIN_MAX) {
                content_length = STDIN_MAX;
            }
        } else {
            // Do not read from stdin if CONTENT_LENGTH is missing
            content_length = 0;
        }

        char * content_buffer = new char[content_length];
        cin.read(content_buffer, content_length);
        content_length = cin.gcount();

        // Chew up any remaining stdin - this shouldn't be necessary
        // but is because mod_fastcgi doesn't handle it correctly.

        // ignore() doesn't set the eof bit in some versions of glibc++
        // so use gcount() instead of eof()...
        do cin.ignore(1024); while (cin.gcount() == 1024);

        string content(content_buffer, content_length);
        delete [] content_buffer;
        return content;
    }

    int main(void) {
        // Backup the stdio streambufs
        streambuf * cin_streambuf  = cin.rdbuf();
        streambuf * cout_streambuf = cout.rdbuf();
        streambuf * cerr_streambuf = cerr.rdbuf();

        FCGX_Request request;

        FCGX_Init();
        FCGX_InitRequest(&request, 0, 0);


        while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0) {
            fcgi_streambuf cin_fcgi_streambuf(request.in);
            fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
            fcgi_streambuf cerr_fcgi_streambuf(request.err);

            cin.rdbuf(&cin_fcgi_streambuf);
            cout.rdbuf(&cout_fcgi_streambuf);
            cerr.rdbuf(&cerr_fcgi_streambuf);

            const char * uri = FCGX_GetParam("REQUEST_URI", request.envp);

            string content = get_request_content(request);

            if (content.length() == 0) {
                content = ", something!";
            }
            const char * mediaType = FCGX_GetParam("REQUEST_METHOD",request.envp);
            string value;
            if(iequals(mediaType,"POST")&&iequals(uri,"/postmethod")) {

                get_request_content(request);
                 cout << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << content.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << content;
            }

            if(iequals(mediaType,"GET")&&iequals(uri,"/getmethod")) {

                string aalu = "this is the new lenght";
                 cout << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " << aalu.length() << "\r\n\r\n" << aalu;
                 FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
            }

            if(iequals(mediaType,"GET")&&iequals(uri,"/redirect")) {

                cout << "HTTP/1.1 301\r\nLocation: http://localhost/getmethod\r\n\r\n";
//              cout << "Status: 301\r\n"
        //                       << "Location: http://localhost/getmethod\r\n";
        //                       << "\r\n";
        //                       << "<html><body>Not Found</body></html>\n";
            }

            if(iequals(mediaType,"GET")&&iequals(uri,"/postredirect")) {     // problem here

                string json = "{\"topic\":\"asdf\",\"message\":\"message\"}";
                cout << "HTTP/1.1 308\r\nLocation: http://localhost/postmethod\r\n\r\n";
//              cout << "Status: 304\r\n"
//                      << "Location: http://localhost/postmethod\r\n"
//                        << "\r\n"
//                          << "<html><body>json</body></html>\n";
            }

            if(iequals(mediaType,"POST")&&iequals(uri,"/getredirect")) {

                            string json = "{\"topic\":\"asdf\",\"message\":\"message\"}";
                            cout << "HTTP/1.1 303\r\nLocation: http://localhost/getmethod\r\n\r\n";
            //              cout << "Status: 304\r\n"
            //                      << "Location: http://localhost/postmethod\r\n"
            //                        << "\r\n"
            //                          << "<html><body>json</body></html>\n";
                        }

            if(iequals(mediaType,"POST")&&iequals(uri,"/posttopostredirect")) {


                                    string json = "{\"topic\":\"adf\",\"message\":\"message\"}";

                                    cout << "Status: 307\r\n"
                                            <<"Location: http://localhost/postmethod\r\n"
                                                <<"\r\n"
                                                <<"\n";

//                                  cout << "Status: 305\r\n"
//                                          << "Location: http://localhost/postmethod\r\n"
//                                            << "\r\n"
//                                              << "<html><body>"+json+"</body></html>\n";
                                }

            if(iequals(mediaType,"GET")&&iequals(uri,"/getttogettredirect")) {

                                                string json = "{\"topic\":\"ssdf\",\"message\":\"message\"}";
                                                cout << "HTTP/1.X 301\r\nLocation: http://localhost/getmethod\r\n\r\n";
            //                                  cout << "Status: 307\r\n"
            //                                          << "Location: http://localhost/postmethod\r\n"
            //                                            << "\r\n";
            //                                              << "<html><body>json</body></html>\n";
                                            }
        }

        // restore stdio streambufs
        cin.rdbuf(cin_streambuf);
        cout.rdbuf(cout_streambuf);
        cerr.rdbuf(cerr_streambuf);

        return 0;
    }
```

/posttopostredirect url is redirecting to /postmethod url. Here, I wish to send json string (above)  when /posttopostredirect is hit to /postmethod url. But couldnot figure out how to do so

Answer (score 0):

Any content of HTTP redirect messages is completely ignored. This has nothing to do with FastCGI. This is how HTTP works. HTTP redirect messages cannot be used to send any content. Well, they could, but the HTTP client will simply ignore it, and issue a `GET` request to the redirected-to URL.

The only thing that can be done is to include any data as parameters encoded in the redirected-to URL. This is done the same way as encoding any parameters in the URL.